# Use google scripts to check if google calendar event has repeat checked

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I would like to use my script to check if an event is repeating.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function eventRepetitions() {
  var events = CalendarApp
                 .getCalendarById("YOUR_EMAIL")
                 .getEvents(new Date(new Date().getTime() + (86400000)*0),
                            new Date(new Date().getTime() + (86400000)*90));

  var eventIDs = events.map(function(e,i,a) { return a[i].getId() });

  Logger.log(eventIDs);

  var eventID     = "ID_CHOSEN_FROM_eventIDs";
  var repetitions = eventIDs.filter(function(e,i,a) { return e == this },eventID).length;

  Logger.log(eventID + " repeats " +
             repetitions + " times in the specified interval.");
}
```

**METHOD OF OPERATION**

1. Enter your email address instead of YOUR_EMAIL. to load your calendar.  You can specify a time range by changing the '0' and '90' in the getEvents method.  They control how many days into the future/past to look for events.  You want this range to be larger than what you expect the event recurrence interval to be.
2. Makes an array of ID's from all the events found in the specified range.
3. Run the function once to populate and log eventIDs. Go to View > Logs to see the list.  If you choose your search range to start right before the event of interest that event's ID will be first.
4. Copy the ID you are looking for in place of "ID_CHOSEN_FROM_eventIDs (you can comment out the 'Logger.log(eventIDs);' line at this point), and run the function again.  Look at the logs and they will tell you if the event is recurring.

There are a lot of ways to improve this code to make it more powerful. For example, if you pass a start date that you know is going to supply the event in question first you can find out if it is repeating in one run of the function.